# Programmatically creating and uploading images in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, python-imaging-library

I'm using this method to create an image programmatically:

```
def create_thumbnail(filename, letters, color):
    img = Image.new('RGB', (200, 200), color=color)
    d = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    font = ImageFont.truetype("sans-serif.ttf", 48)
    d.text((0, 0), letters, (255, 255, 255), font=font)
    img.save("{}.png".format(filename))
```

This is my object creation logic:

```
room, created = Room.objects.get_or_create(name=name, logo="", sport=sport,status=RoomStatus.ACTIVE,defaults={'team': team,'city': city,})
```

I've an override in the model to save the image to the correct folder.

```
def image_upload_path(instance, filename):
    pattern = re.compile(r'\s+')
    filename = re.sub(pattern, '', filename)
    return 'images/rooms/logo/_{0}/{1}'.format(instance.id, filename)
```

This works fine when handling a post request with the image data.

How do I create the image and upload it the correct folder using my image creation function?

Comment: Is your image creation function running somewhere outside of your Django app (i.e. does it run standalone)?

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what you want but the `upload_to` argument of the imagefield may be what you need